# C# String generator

Tags: c#, generator

Im new to C# and I was wondering if you guys could help me out. First of all I am making a pretty simple generator.  I want it to give me a default string everytime I press the generate button.(The string is 00000001008) then I want to add a random number/letter onto the end of that, this number/letter will have to be 3-9/A-F. then i want another string consisting of letters and/or numbers going 0-9 and A-F. I have the normal concept down and here is what I have so far:

```
public string GenerateRandomCode(ref int length)
{
    string charPool = "ABCDEF1234567890";
    StringBuilder rs = new StringBuilder();
    Random random = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        rs.Append(charPool[(int)(random.NextDouble() * charPool.Length)]);
    }
    return rs.ToString();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = "00000001008";
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: How to get the strings at the end to go into the textBox1.Text

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Not sure what `Random` you are using, but there's no `NextDouble()` method in .NET's `System.Random` class.

Comment: @user3138797 `textBox1.Text += "Your text here";` :) Also be careful when passing value types by ref.

Comment: Are you asking how to call a method and assign its result into a property? Did you read any C# tutorial or book?

Comment: no :( I just jumped right into the language like a noob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to (assuming your random class works):

```
public string GenerateRandomCode(int length)
{
    string charPool = "ABCDEF1234567890";
    StringBuilder rs = new StringBuilder();
    Random random = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        rs.Append(charPool[(int)(random.NextDouble() * charPool.Length)]);
    }
    return rs.ToString();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = "00000001008" + GenerateRandomCode(1);
}
```

You could generate a hex string though I think with (which will fulfill requirement for generating 0-9, A-F - 11 characters long):

```
textBox1.Text = String.Format("{0:X11}", new Random().Next(0x100000000000))
```

or (should give vals "00000001008" + x3-xF) ...

```
public string GenerateRandomCode()
{
    return "00000001008" + string.Format("{0:X1}", new Random().Next(12) + 3));
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = GenerateRandomCode();
}
```

Comment: But i also want the 00000001008 at the beginning of the textBox's text

Comment: Thanks bro, appreciate your help :)

Comment: I hope this is what you are after

Comment: it was, just the fact that I wanted the seperate byte of just 3-9/A-F after the initial string

Comment: @user3138797 please see last revision and mark as answer if it works, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
public string GenerateRandomCode(int length)
{
    var chars = "ABCDEF1234567890";
    var random = new Random();
    return new string(
        Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
              .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)])
              .ToArray()
    );
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = GenerateRandomCode(11);
}
```